# Send and HTTP request to Sharepoint with attachment

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, flow, send-email

I've created a flow that will send an email to my group whenever there's a new request from our SharePoint site.

I would like to add/attach an attachment in sending the email from sharepoint list.

I've used HTTP request to Sharepoint. Using this:

```
Site Address: \sharepoint_site\
Method: POST
Uri: _api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail
Headers: accept = application/json;odata=nometadata
         content-type = application/json;odata=nometadata
Body: { 
       'properties':{
       'To':['email@email.com']
       'Body': 'Hello world!'
       'Subject': 'Request #1'
        }
      }
```

I don't how to add the attached file from the list. My goal is on every request we will received an email with attachments and the attached file will be automatically delete when the flow is successful.

Any idea on how it will work?.

thanks in advance.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Why are you not using **Send an email** action in microsoft flow like [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Send-email-with-excel-as-attachment/td-p/116353)?

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap, I've already tried using **Send an email** action, it works well, but the **From(Send as)** address was sent on behalf of me, since I am the one who created the flow. I want **no-reply@sharepointonline.com** to be the Send as address which works in Send an HTTP request action.

Comment: Are you not able to enter this email in **From** textbox?

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes I tried to input the email of the requester which is included on the sharepoint list. But I'm getting an error, it says that I not allowed/authorize to use that email...

Comment: you tried putting this `no-reply@sharepointonline.com` email in `From` section?

Comment: @GaneshSanap, yes I've tried it already but getting the same error not authorized.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is using Send Email Action item(outlook 365). Below is how it will look, you can add attachment directly in action by using File content as dynamic data. As you are doing on List with attachments flow would be little long. Below is screenshot for your reference. Just tried this, it is working.

[image]

Important note - In below ContentBytes should be added as expression

body('Get_attachment_content').$content

[image]

Below action should be outside of ApplyForEach loop.

[image]

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for your answer. :) But if I used that way it will send automatically on my behalf even though I'm not the one who created/adding a request. Since I am the one who created the flow. :)

Comment: did you try to put From email address?